# Setting the SelectedIndex on ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am in a beginning C# class and I am having trouble figuring out why after the following code runs, the selected index is still -1 (i.e. the combobox at load is empty). It should be defaulting to selectedIndex = 1:

```
public string[,] GetArray()
    {
        //create array with conversion values
        string[,] conversionInfo = { {"Miles","Kilometers", "1.6093"},
                                     {"Kilometers","Miles", ".6214"},
                                     {"Feet","Meters", ".3048"},
                                     {"Meters","Feet","3.2808"},
                                     {"Inches","Centimeters", "2.54"},
                                     {"Centimeters","Inches",".3937"}};
        return conversionInfo;
    }

    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get array to use
        string[,] conversionChoices = GetArray();

        //load conversion combo box with values
        StringBuilder fillString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < conversionChoices.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < conversionChoices.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
            {
                fillString.Append(conversionChoices[i, j]);

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    fillString.Append(" to ");
                }
            }
            cboConversion.Items.Add(fillString);
            fillString.Clear();
        }

        //set default selected value for combobox
        cboConversion.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }

    public void cboConversions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelSet(cboConversion.SelectedIndex);
    }

    public void LabelSet(int selection)
    {

        //get array to use
        string[,] labelChoices = GetArray();

        //set labels to coorespond with selection
        string from = labelChoices[selection, 0];
        string to = labelChoices[selection, 1];
        lblFrom.Text = from + ":";
        lblTo.Text = to + ":";
    }
```

This is a class assignment so I am not allowed to set anything using the designer, other than to link methods to event. Everything works correctly except for the default for the combobox.

Comment: You say "It should be defaulting to selectedIndex 1" but you set the combobox SelectedIndex to 0 in the code.

Comment: He has done it right, because 0 is the first element of the list.

Comment: I know that.  The question as written says she wants the item at SelectedIndex  of 1, not the first element in the list, which would be index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely correct, but you have one single fault in your mind. Consider, that you are loading the items into the ComboBox after you have initialized the control. At this point the control have no items, therefore the property "Text" is not setted automatically.

You have to differ between the SelectedIndex, which is the index of the item in the list of items, and the Text, which is the text, shown in the ComboBox. So think about when and how you should set the Text-property of the ComboBox.

Always set the Text-property to the first value of your item-list, after you changed it.

Greetings,

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added this line (cboConversion.Text = conversionChoices[0, 0] + " to " + conversionChoices[0, 1];) at the bottom of the form load method and it is working now. I appreciate your not just giving me code, but explaining why, which is really more helpful since I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

the answer of Mario can be interpreted also as:

put your code after the loading (example: on the shown event), in this way the control is initialized and has items.